# Objects appear in wrong sections when grouping and sorting

Tags: magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to fetch Core Data objects and display them in sections in a `UITableView` grouped by the (non-transient) entity property `groupAttribute`:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = 
    [Post fetchAllGroupedBy: @"groupAttribute" 
        withPredicate:predicate 
        sortedBy:@"groupAttribute,publishDate" 
        ascending:NO 
        delegate:self];
```

`predicate` just does some filtering stuff, nothing special.

After inserting some objects, the table view puts them into wrong sections. However, the sorting of the rows are correct. It's basically the same phenomenon [Richard Warrender describes in his blog](http://richardwarrender.com/2010/10/core-data-objects-in-wrong-sections/), but with usage of MagicalRecord and *after* adding the second sort descriptor (note that `sortedBy` produces one sort descriptor for each comma-separated attribute).

What's going wrong here?

Comment: did you get answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. If you got one, please share it.